# Writing Golf Code cleaner than the basic code

Tags: javascript, arrays

Solved this problem using the below method. But would any JavaScript developer who is experienced could write this in a cleaner way? I was thinking you can loop through the "names" array and make the code cleaner but no matter how much I try it doesn't make sense outside of this box. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!  Just trying to challenge myself into the next phase...

```
var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  if (strokes == 1) {
    return names[0]
  } else if (strokes <= par - 2) {
    return names[1]
  } else if (strokes == par - 1) {
    return names[2]
  } else if (strokes == par) {
    return names[3]
  } else if (strokes == par + 1) {
    return names[4]
  } else if (strokes == par + 2) {
    return names[5]
  } else if (strokes >= par + 3) {
    return names[6]
  }
}
```

Comment: `could write this in a cleaner way` depends what you mean with clearer. Why do you use an array instead of writing `if (strokes == 1) { return "Hole-in-one!" } …`, with `return names[0]` one needs to look up what the contents of the array at that index to see if the correct text is returned, so why do choose to use an array?.

Comment: You've missed a double eagle, or albatross (-3 delta), also a hole in one on a par 5 - i.e. -4 delta (should have a special "cheater!" entry for that one).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't belong on Stack Overflow but on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @t.niese it was an exercise, not much of my own logic; I also thought it would make sense for them to use an array since those names never change based on the rules of Golf? Definitely trying to see what other experienced coders would write this out as. Good responses so far. Amazing collaboration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check with direct values or by using the delta and return the found value or a default value.

```
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
    if (strokes === 1) return names[0];
    var delta = strokes - par;
    if (delta <= -2 ) return names[1];
    return names[delta + 3] || names[6];
}

var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];
//                             -2          -1     0       1          2              3
```

Comment: I like this way! I have never seen someone use negative values to derive the result from!

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];
function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  if (strokes <= 1) { // special case
    return names[0]
  } 

  if (strokes >= par + 3) { // higher bound
    return names[6]
  }

  if(strokes - par - 2 + 1 < 1) { // lower bound - not handled :<
    return "No name for this one, boi"
  }

  // in between
  return strokes[strokes - par - 2 + 1]; 
  // TODO: Name magic numbers
}
```

Of course it depends if names will change.
If so, then I would make this code array-length dependant.
And of course, tests are needed.

Note: I've never played golf.

Answer (score 0):

In the following solution function `index` is used to convert the delta to an index in the names array.

If the number of strokes is 1, then we pass an identifiable non-number (NaN), so a hole-in-one can be detected. Otherwise, we normalise values less than -2 or greater than 3.

```js
let names = [ 'Hole-in-one!', 'Eagle!', 'Birdie!', 'Par', 'Bogey!', 'Double Bogey!', 'Go Home!']

const index = Δ => isNaN(Δ) 
  ? 0 
  : Δ <= -2 
    ? 1 
    : Δ >= 3 
      ? 6 
      : +Δ+3

const golfScore = (par, strokes) => names[index(strokes == 1 ? NaN : strokes-par)]

console.log(golfScore(3,3)) // 'Par'
```